# Is this good idea to change current application mode from Env.php

Tags: magento2, developer-mode

I have see all  answer of question,
[How do I set Developer Mode in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13125/how-do-i-set-developer-mode-in-magento-2/109052#109052)

All are good.

But suddenly **i got another solution myself** ,by directly change `MAGE_MODE` value at `env.php`(`app/etc/`  ) and here change **current application mode from default to developer** by `MAGE_MODE' => 'default'` to `MAGE_MODE' => 'developer'` .

and it been works.

**But now my question is that this a good solution for change Application mode?**.

Please put your views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what `bin/magento deploy:mode:set` is doing.

See [`Magento\Deploy\Model\Mode::setStoreMode()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/app/code/Magento/Deploy/Model/Mode.php#L129-L143):

```
/**
 * Store mode in env.php
 *
 * @param string $mode
 * @return void
 */
protected function setStoreMode($mode)
{
    $data = [
        ConfigFilePool::APP_ENV => [
            State::PARAM_MODE => $mode
        ]
    ];
    $this->writer->saveConfig($data);
}
```

Generally, `env.php` is a generated file that is not meant to be modified manually. Changing values there will work though, as they are read from the file before any other changes are made automatically.

In conclusion, you can do it but there should be no reason to if you have access to the `bin/magento` CLI tool.

Comment: last conclusion is seem  good .

Answer (score 2):

After some time experimenting with modes, especially with deployment workflows, I'd like to highlight a slight difference btw setting mode via `bin/magento` and changing the `app/etc/env.php` file.

The `bin/magento deploy:mode:set production` automatically triggers other actions, such as setting maintenance mode, deploying static contents, compiling DI etc.

In some circumstances (like during a deployment process) you would like to have control on these actions, thus changing the `app/etc/env.php` manually could be a viable option.

Hope it helps.