# Magento 2 setup:upgrade to update modules breaks layout and have to redeploy

Tags: magento2

Many guides I read state just running setup:upgrade or clearing the cache will result in changes to modules being made apparent, but if I just clear the cache it doesn't help, even if I delete all the files in the var/generation and var/page_cache and var/di and var/cache folders and run magento cache:clean.  Running magento setup:upgrade break the site, no js or css is there at all unless I rerun setup:di:compile and setup:static-content:deploy yet the site is in development mode with caching disabled, so why do I have to re compile and re deploy for every change to a module?  It seems broken :(  Especially as all these guides say just setup:upgrade or cache:clean should show my changes, which I'm not understanding why need run if I'm in development mode with cache disabled?  Any help greatly appreciated, waiting to redeploy for any change I want to see is very time consuming.

Comment: Yeah, extremely time consuming.  Setup grunt on your local to compile your LESS.  You can use the standard way when deploying to server.  I wrote a script for those commands on my server, and use Grunt on local.  My 2 cents.  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer finally.  My server uses php-fpm and there was something weird with it not setting developer mode properly this page helped me:
[How do I set Developer Mode in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13125/how-do-i-set-developer-mode-in-magento-2)

As did the people on this page so upvoted them :)  The post that helped me the most was setting developer mode in the php-fpm pool.  I also have to restart php-fpm service on each change but it then shows up immediately, even if I don't run cache:clean.  So I'll need to fix something with php-fpm but this is not a magento issue and you guys helped me so thank you.

To further this, to fix it totally I had to set these in a php.ini file for me this was in /etc/php.d/10-opcache.ini

```
opcache.enable = 0
opcache.enable_cli = 0
```

and for the environment variable in /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

```
env[MAGE_MODE] = developer
```

Then restarting php-fpm

```
service php-fpm restart
```

And my changes to phtml files show up immediately now.

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

`setup:upgrade :` If you enabled one or more modules, then you will need to run magento setup:upgrade to update the database schema.

`Setup:upgrade :` it not require run on every changes in module.

`cache:clean :` if it enable from admin then you have to clean after any changes in code, but if it disable from admin then no need to run cache:clean command.

When we run setup:upgrade command after that we have to deploy static content, else no need to deploy static content.

Comment: I made a change to a phtml file, and nothing I do will make the change show have tried:
setup:upgrade
cache:clean
setup:di:compile
setup:static-content:deploy

I have tried following the docs: 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html#config-mode-change under set to developer mode
as well as the advice on this page:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

My last change I messed with stuff for 40 mins to get it to show, please help.

Comment: if you have modify phtml code then you have to run php bin/magento cache:clean and check your changes.

Comment: I ran that, and there are no changes, it's still showing old text that isn't even in any file on the server.  I verified it is in developer mode and caching is disabled.  Browser cache is also disabled.  I also had to change env.php before and the only way to get it to change was delete the file and run magento till I got an error, then put the modified file back in.

Comment: Also accept my answer if you have really use for  resolve issue.